# How can I merge 2 data properties and show them in a single Column of DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to merge and display 2 data fields in 1 column in the `DataGridView`. How is this possible in vb.net?

The `DataGridView` has a DataSource.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either of these options:

- Creating a computed Column for DataTable
- Creating a read-only Property for Class
- Handling CellFormatting event of DataGridView

**Creating a computed Column for DataTable**

If data fields belongs to a `DataTable` you can add a computed `DataColumn` to your `DataTable` and set its [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property to return desired value based on those two columns.

```
table.Columns.Add("DisplayName", GetType(String), "FirstName + ' ' + LastName")
```

**Creating a read-only Property for Class**

If data fields belongs to a plain model class you can add a read only property which in the getter, return desired value based on those 2 properties.

```
Public Class Person
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public ReadOnly Property DisplayName As String
        Get
            Return String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

**Using CellFormatting event of DataGridView**

As a general solution for all cases, you can use [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of `DataGridView` and set `e.Value` to desired value based on those two fields.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object,  _
    e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    ' For example you want to do it for 3rd column
    If e.ColumnIndex = 2 AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then   
        Dim row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        'If DataSource is a DataTable, DataBoundItem is DataRowView
        Dim data = DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, Person)
        e.Value = String.Format("{0} {1}", data.FirstName, data.LastName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems the post answers your question and it would be great if you accept the answer or let me know if you have any question about the answer :)