# Datagridview multiplication two column and checking value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I want to check values in grid columns when performing multiplication between Quantity and Price values. I have done this and it works perfectly!

But I have a problem when I enter a string value in column Quantity or after I edit the column and leave it empty. I am getting an error:

[image]

So how can I check the values and when the user types string, char or blank input, show a `MessageBox` with feedback?

Here is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int price, quantity, total;         

             quantity= int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString());
             cena = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Price"].Value.ToString());
             total = quantity * price ;

            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = total;
        }
```

When I enter an integer everything works OK...

Comment: If your data was in a datatable you could use an expression column to automatically multiply the total.  Otherwise this is a dupe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I know what is that exception. I need like i say how to check what type of value is entered in cell

Comment: If you just added some columns and did not set the datatype, they will all be string.  use `TryParse` for cases where they enter letters or spaces (or force the type to some numerics)

Comment: Forget about `CellEndEdit` or all other events. Just use computed column in your `DataTable`. [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you are looking for.

Comment: my cumns is not in `DataTable` becouse i manually create grid `dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "quatity"`.. etc

Comment: So create a `DataTable` first! Don't use `DataGridView` without data source.

Comment: Ok i will create few tests with `DataTable` and will check

Comment: Take a look at this post [How can I merge 2 data properties and show them in a single Column of DataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39140273/3110834)

Comment: @Ivan Let me know if you have any question about linked post.

Comment: Ah sorry forgot for this. I slove problem woth `DataTable`

Comment: Good job, you used the best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and assign some value if the input is not able to convert to int.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                int price, quantity, total;         

   if(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value != null)
    {
        if(!int.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString(), out quantity))
            {
                 quantity= 0;
            }
    }else
    {
        quantity= 0;
    }    
                             price = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Price"].Value.ToString());

                     total = quantity * price ;

                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = total;
                }
```

Comment: This return the some error in both cases woth string and blanko cell

Comment: Error when you leave the value blank or when you enter some string value?

Comment: Error when i enter string. Error when i enter in edit mode cell and leave it empty

Comment: I have included sample code only for price. Have you included the code change for both quantity and price?

Comment: Am only need to edit quantity! I dont touch price col and total col

Comment: May be NULL issue, updated the code handle it. Pls check now.

Answer (score 0):

Use the try... catch block code

```
        void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){ 

           int price, quantity, total;         
           try {
                 quantity= int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value.ToString());
                 cena = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Price"].Value.ToString());
                 total = quantity * price ;

                 dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"].Value = total;
           } catch(NullReferenceException)  { ... }
       }
```

You can do nullable type

```
int? price, quantity, total;
```

And read here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This slove problem when  col is blank but not slove when i enter `char` or `string`. When i enter char or string i get `An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`  `Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: The System.FormatException is because your code is not converting the string to integer, Int32.Parse(...)